# Use sequelize only with raw queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I don't know much of sequelize. I have not even worked much in backend before.

I have to work on a project where the database with data already exists and the backend used was php.

Do I have to create models and use standard sequelize querying or is it possible to only use raw queries for the entire application?

Answer (score 0):

try this link it will help u sure https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html

```
        const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');
        const users = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `users`", { type: 
        QueryTypes.SELECT });
```